# Upload file using selenium to bootsrap-fileinput with geckodriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-file-upload

I would like to know how to upload a file to a [bootstrap-fileinput](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput) element using Selenium with the FirefoxDriver. I tried

```
WebElement input = letter.findElement(By.cssSelector("#letter input"));
input.sendKeys("/home/me/loremIpsum.pdf");
```

I get

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: File not found: /home/me/loremIpsum.pdf
```

Of course the file `/home/me/loremIpsum.pdf` does exist.

The same code works using the chromedriver.

I've put together a jsfiddle to show the fileinput button: https://jsfiddle.net/yscgx2zc/

The rendered html from my app (copied from Firefox developer console) looks like this. Find the `input` element close to the bottom.

```
<div id="letter" class="form-group"><label class="control-label">The Letter<span>*</span></label><div class="file-input file-input-new"><div class="file-preview ">
    <div class="close fileinput-remove">×</div>
    <div class="file-drop-disabled">
    <div class="file-preview-thumbnails">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>    <div class="file-preview-status text-center text-success"></div>
    <div class="kv-fileinput-error file-error-message" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="kv-upload-progress hide"><div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%;">
        0%
     </div>
</div></div>
<div class="input-group file-caption-main">
   <div tabindex="500" class="form-control file-caption  kv-fileinput-caption">
   <div class="file-caption-name"></div>
</div>

   <div class="input-group-btn">
       <button type="button" tabindex="500" title="Clear selected files" class="btn btn-default fileinput-remove fileinput-remove-button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>  <span class="hidden-xs">Remove</span></button>
       <button type="button" tabindex="500" title="Abort ongoing upload" class="btn btn-default hide fileinput-cancel fileinput-cancel-button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>  <span class="hidden-xs">Cancel</span></button>

       <div tabindex="500" class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>&nbsp;  <span class="hidden-xs">Browse …</span>
       <input data-show-upload="false" data-allowed-file-extensions="[&quot;pdf&quot;]" data-allowed-file-types="[&quot;pdf&quot;]" accept="application/pdf" class="file" id="1502961793221" type="file"></div>
   </div>
</div></div></div>
```

Comment: Somehow I am unable to locate the `tagName("input")` in the HTML provided in the question. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DebanjanB thanks, I've edited the sourcecode to make it easier to find (at the bottom).

Comment: Probably [this bug](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/858).

Comment: Looks like the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following code block:

```
WebElement input = letter.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='1502957288010']"));
input.sendKeys("/home/me/loremIpsum.pdf");
```

Comment: Thanks, i've updated my question again. The input element was already found. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to upload a file to http://plugins.krajee.com/file-basic-usage-demo, which is a demo page for specified bootstrap file input.

Works both on Firefox and Chrome. The only issue was with input visibility. When I made it visible, I was able to upload a file.

However, your error message seems pretty obvious to me. Your file wasn't found on disk. Describe your environment please. Are you using local or remote `WebDriver`? As in case of remote, this file should be present on target VM, where browser is started.

Comment: I'm on a linux system and testing against Firefox. When I do an `ls` on the file named in the error message (copy pasted) it is found. How did you make it visible. I tried `js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='visible'", input);`

Comment: For demo sample I've been using jQuery to remove parent element's class, which hides required input: `executeScript("$(\".btn.btn-primary.btn-file\").removeClass(\"btn-file\");");`

Comment: @bastian which selenium / driver / browser version are using?

Comment: It is still hidden when using your code. The Browse button just gets larger. I'm using Selenium 3.4.0, Firefox 55.0.1 and geckodriver 0.18.0

Comment: @bastian I've tried on a demo site (bootstrap), not yours. So you have to find a class, which is used for component's visibility control. But... According to exception, your issue is not related to input's invisibility. If you're 100% sure that file exists, I'd also try another browser, just to check if the issue persists. As geckodriver is not stable at moment. So I wouldn't exclude the probability of a bug in a driver itself (or just OS specific). Btw, I've tried on Mac OS X.

Comment: Seems to be a geckodriver bug. Using chromium with chromedriver it works even without making the element visible.

Comment: Then you may want to raise this issue in Geckodriver tracker. :)